# shallow Button in React Enzyme throws error "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, addeventlistener, createelement

I want to simulate a click on Button and check if onClick was called or not.
Here I am not using JEST or SINON to mock or spy instead using my own spy.

```
const DeselectAll = (props: Props) => (
  <div className="deselectall">
    <Button
      className="deselectall--button"
      icon="minus"
      onClick={props.clearItems}
      text={translate("deselectall")}
    />
  </div>
);
```

test

```
function MySpy() {
  this.calls = 0;
}
  MySpy.prototype.fn = function () {
    return () => this.calls++;
  }
When(/^Deselect button is clicked$/, function () {
    const mySpy = new MySpy();
    const mockCallBack = mySpy.fn();

    const wrapper = mount(DeselectAll);
    const button = enzyme.shallow(React.createElement(Button, { onClick: mockCallBack })); 
                                                          //error: seems button is not yet 
                                                          // available 
    button.find('.deselectall--button').simulate('click');
    expect(mySpy.calls).to.be.equal(1);
});
```

ERROR: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Any help appreciated!